# Web scraping and reshaping data

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a problem when tidying a table from website **scraping**.
I want to get the table (with header V1 to V5) from the link below, but I failed to convert it into the same format in R studio.

This is what I'm doing

```
url <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/using-control-charts-in-r/"
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
h <- read_html(url)
tab <- h %>% html_nodes("table") 
tab <- tab[[2]] %>% html_table()
 
tab <- separate_rows(tab, 1, sep = " ")
tab <- tab[8:132,]
tab <- as.data.frame(tab)
 
tab1 <- data.frame(c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"))
tab1 <- tab1 %>% setNames("Cat")
tab2 <- cbind(tab1,tab)
 
tab3 <- tab2 %>% spread(key = Cat, X1)
```

Here is the result

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 125 rows:
* 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71, 76, 81, 86, 91, 96, 101, 106, 111, 116, 121
* 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57, 62, 67, 72, 77, 82, 87, 92, 97, 102, 107, 112, 117, 122
* 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 58, 63, 68, 73, 78, 83, 88, 93, 98, 103, 108, 113, 118, 123
* 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84, 89, 94, 99, 104, 109, 114, 119, 124
* 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125
```

So what should I do to get the same table as from the website?

And if you can think of a better way to get the table from this website, please tell me.

P/s: I'm learning R programming on my own, so please teach me!

Cheers.

Comment: FYI “scrapping” means throwing away - the correct term is __scraping__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way :

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/using-control-charts-in-r/"

url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes('table') %>%
  .[[2]] %>%
  html_table() %>%
  dplyr::pull(X1) %>%
  stringr::str_extract_all('\\d+\\.\\d+') %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  matrix(ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% type.convert() -> tab

tab
#     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
#1  1.45 1.56 1.40 1.45 1.33
#2  1.75 1.53 1.55 1.42 1.42
#3  1.60 1.41 1.35 1.52 1.36
#4  1.53 1.58 1.54 1.71 1.55
#5  1.48 1.34 1.64 1.59 1.46
#6  1.69 1.55 1.49 1.61 1.47
#...
#...
```

Comment: Nice. Does type.convert() examine the data structure and decide on the most appropriate datatype then apply it to all values (when left as default)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It handles each column separately and applies the most suitable datatype for that column. So this will also work when you have character values in one of the column.

Comment: It looks like data.frame does an implicit conversion as well.

Comment: It looks like it has converted the values to numbers but they are still characters. You can check that by adding `... data.frame %>% str`.

Comment: That's weird isn't it? How is it that one can have string literals without quotes? I'm still a beginner in R. Good to be aware of this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain how the table regenerated its header (V1 to V5)?

Comment: If there are no headers in your data `as.data.frame` by default generates column name as `V1`, `V2`, `V3`.... If you use `data.frame` it will generate `X1`, `X2`, `X3`....